# Lxd zfs is not clear what to do

Tags: lxc, zfs, lxd

Unfortunately lxd has very short and uncomplete document site...
I launched a container on my needs but after many successful and wasted tests !

Now i configured lxd and use zfs file system and create new zfs pool with 1800GB size

I dont know whats that size ?

df -h shows my 1 raided partitions and some containers name as a zfs partition that each of them has 1800 gb total space.

Now i want to know Its true or wrong configuration for zfs?
Total available space is 1800GB on my server and i wanna make several linux vps and give each of them a diffrent space
Should i use diffrent zpool for each of them every time ?
I wish you get my mean !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lxd configured properly to use zfs, then it will give you one zfs dataset per container. Something like this:

```
NAME                                                                                        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
nsn7/lxd                                                                                   12,8G   241G    19K  /nsn7/lxd
nsn7/lxd/containers                                                                        10,9G   241G    19K  /nsn7/lxd/containers
nsn7/lxd/containers/maas-19-trusty-pxe5                                                    5,67G   241G  6,05G  /var/lib/lxd/containers/maas-19-trusty-pxe5.zfs
nsn7/lxd/containers/maas-20-xenial-pxe5                                                    5,21G   241G  5,51G  /var/lib/lxd/containers/maas-20-xenial-pxe5.zfs
nsn7/lxd/containers/maas-20-xenial-pxe5@snapshot-maas-2.0b4                                 106M      -  5,62G  -
```

In the above output, I even have a snapshotted container, and lxd used a native zfs snapshot for that.

It's not clear what your other questions are. Maybe start with comparing your `zfs list -t all -r` output with mine above and go from there?

Comment: after some working and searches i found what zfs using for !
now i have one question , can we make a pool as large as total capacity of hdd ?
does it make any problem for main server ?